# how to call smart contract method from web3.js using java script

Tags: smartcontracts, web3js, ibm-blockchain

A smart contract method has already been deployed and I want to call a method using javascript. How can I do that?

```
contractABI = ABI json;
contractAddress = ('my addess');`
```

Comment: From web3js documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12 and if you want a call and not a transaction: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call

Comment: If you can't figure it out from the documentation update the question with the code you tried and what errors you are getting.